# Why does ~username/ change to /home/username if tab-completing a path with a space in it?

Tags: bash, path, autocomplete, tab-completion

In `~jacksonc/temp/` there are two files, `test.txt` and `space test.txt`, both placed there through Windows (using Samba).

Using bash, if I type

`cat ~jacksonc/temp/t[tab]`

, it autocompletes to

`cat ~jacksonc/temp/test.txt`

However, if I type

`cat ~jacksonc/temp/s[tab]`

it autocompletes to

`cat /home/jacksonc/temp/space\ test.txt`

My question isn't about the backslash, I know why that's there. I'm curious as to why the space causes the ~ to be expanded though?

Comment: *shrug* it doesn't do the same thing for me (using bash 4.1.5 in Linux). It could just be a bug.

Comment: I doubt it. More likely it's a user setting, as Drav Sloan suggested.

Comment: Just to provide another data point, using the default settings on current Ubuntu, `bash` expands `~` to the actual path when using tab completion regardless of whether there's a space in the path or not. I have no idea why the space would make a difference either; I've never heard of such a thing before.

Comment: Mmm. Unfortunately, I can't give too many details on the system I'm using, as my work uses its own internal Linux distribution, though I believe it's essentially re-badged Redhat from like, 6 years ago.

Comment: One extra thing though, is that ~ always expands upon tab-completion when in ksh, which is the default shell. But if I fire up bash it only happens with a space in the path. Weird.

Comment: Here on ubuntu 10.04, with bash_completion installed ~ with a space in the path does not expand. It is a bit of a weird one though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine because your system has bash_completion script http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ installed, which can alter the behaviour of things like this.

Normally this expansion can be turned off via readline options. In your `~/.inputrc` file put the following in it:

```
expand-tilde off
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I wouldn't know, I'm SSH'd into a server somewhere in this building. Any idea, though, why this happens only when a space is in the path? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I just checked, and there's no `~/.inputrc` file in my home directory, so it's not this. It must be something similar though, seeing as different people are getting different results with ~ being expanded.

Comment: Well it's more that the `~/inputrc` can effect the behaviour of this expansion. I personally suspect bash_completion (a set of autocomplete routines compiled to expand the default autocomplete of bash; it's an _addition_ to the stand bash install.  Signs of that are a directory `/etc/bash_completion.d/` or a file `/etc/bash_completion`.

Comment: Accepting this answer. I don't think it's correct in the exact thing causing the effect (ie bash_completion), but most likely it's some other script doing the same thing. So this is correct in principle :)